# CreateFileMapping fails with hFile other than INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7

update - solved and answered, offending lines have been commented out

**Brief description**

I am having a problem linking CreateFile with CreateFileMapping even though I use (GENERIC_WRITE or GENERIC_WRITE) for CreateFile, with PAGE_READWRITE for CreateFileMapping

**Detailed description**

I am using CreateFileMapping to share memory between proceses.
the actual mechanics of that is working fine, assuming I don't map to a physical file and instead use INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE for the first parameter to CreateFileMapping. This is fine, however what I'd like to achieve is for the main process that creates this map to use a disk based file, and flush it to the drive, periodically, and when it shuts down, so the data is automatically saved.

**Code follows...**
(when i run this, i get "Error 5 : Access is Denied" as the ShowMessage)

```
const MaximumMapSize = 256 * 1024;
var virtualMemoryPath : string = '';

function getFileHandle(mapname : string; maxSize  : dword) :THandle;
var diskfilename : string;

  lpFileName: PChar;
  dwDesiredAccess: DWORD;
  dwShareMode: DWORD;
  lpSecurityAttributes: PSecurityAttributes;
  dwCreationDisposition : dword;
  dwFlagsAndAttributes: DWORD;
  hTemplateFile : THandle ;

  temp : pointer;
begin
    Result := INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    if (maxSize <= MaximumMapSize) and (Length(virtualMemoryPath) > 0) then
    begin

            diskfilename := virtualMemoryPath+mapname+'.bin';

            if FileExists(diskfilename) then
               Sysutils.DeleteFile(diskfilename);

            lpFileName              := PChar(diskfilename);
            //dwDesiredAccess         := GENERIC_WRITE or GENERIC_WRITE;//<<<wrong
            dwDesiredAccess         := GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE;
            dwShareMode             := 0;//FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE;//<<wrong
            lpSecurityAttributes    := nil;
            dwCreationDisposition   := CREATE_ALWAYS;
            dwFlagsAndAttributes    := 0;
            hTemplateFile           := 0 ;


            Result := CreateFile(
                lpFileName,
                dwDesiredAccess,
                dwShareMode,
                lpSecurityAttributes,
                dwCreationDisposition,
                dwFlagsAndAttributes,
                hTemplateFile);

           if (Result <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then
           begin
             GetMem(temp,maxsize);
             ZeroMemory(temp,maxsize);
             FileWrite(result,temp^,maxSize);
             FreeMem (temp,maxsize);
             FlushFileBuffers(result);
             SetFilePointer(result,0,0,FILE_BEGIN);
           end;
    end;
end;

function createMap (mapname : string ; maxSize: dword; var hFile: THandle) : THandle;
var
    lpFileMappingAttributes: PSecurityAttributes;
    flProtect           : DWORD;
    dwMaximumSizeHigh   : DWORD;
    dwMaximumSizeLow    : DWORD;
    lpName              : PChar;

    LastError : dword;
begin

    Result := INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    if (maxSize > MaximumMapSize) then
        exit;

     // create a disk the file or return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE if settings have not defined a path to folder
     hFile     :=  getFileHandle(mapname,maxSize);

     lpFileMappingAttributes := nil;
     flProtect          := PAGE_READWRITE;
     dwMaximumSizeHigh  := 0;
     dwMaximumSizeLow   := maxSize;
     lpName := PChar(mapname);

     Result := CreateFileMapping(
        hfile,
        lpFileMappingAttributes,
        flProtect,
        dwMaximumSizeHigh,
        dwMaximumSizeLow,
        lpName);

     if (Result = 0) then
     begin

         if (not (hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) ) then
            CloseHandle(hFile);

         hFile := 0;
         LastError := GetLastError();
         ShowMessage( Format('Error %d : %s',[LastError,SysErrorMessage(LastError)]) );

     end
     else
     begin

        ShowMessage(Format('Returing handle %d',[result]));
        if (hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then
            hFile := 0;

     end;

end;
```

Comment: So, what happens when you run this code? And could you please format the code?

Comment: sorry i have updated the question. it tells me access is denied (GetLastError()= 5). i had mentioned it earlier, but had pruned the question as it was getting very long winded, so i deleted a paragraph.

Comment: and it does create the file, which is the correct size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is here:

```
GENERIC_WRITE or GENERIC_WRITE
```

You meant:

```
GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE
```

Fix that and your file mapping can be created.

I agree with Hans that you should not be sharing the file handle.

Comment: well spotted on the GENERIC_WRITE or GENERIC_WRITE. i disagree with you about the order of the parameters though. the winapi function won't allow you to swap the order around just because you feel like it! they are listed in the correct order.

Comment: "The winapi function won't allow you to swap the order around just because you feel like it!" Well quite. But it wasn't because I felt like it. I just read it wrong. That's all! Silly me!

Answer (score 5):

```
        dwDesiredAccess         := GENERIC_WRITE or GENERIC_WRITE;
        dwShareMode             := FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE;
```

This cannot work.  You'll need read and write access.  Also, creating a view requires the operating system to be sure that it is the only one that can write to the file.  There's no mechanism to detect another process writing to the file, other than through a view, and ensure that such a write is visible in memory in a timely and synchronous manner.  Particularly the synchronous update is impossible to implement with multiple threads accessing the view.

Read sharing is similarly unwise, the operating system provides no guarantee at which time it updates the file from the view.  The only guarantee is that it will be updated when all views are closed.  Which also means that an orderly shutdown of Windows is required, you cannot make this reliable against mishaps like a power loss. Again, reads need to be done through the view, not the file.  The only appropriate choice is no sharing.

Comment: except that was one of the first things i tried. no difference in the result. (with 0 as the dwShareMode  flag).

Comment: It's clearly not the correct share mode, but the system still lets you do it if you so wish. In other words, this is not the cause of `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

Comment: Sigh, hard to answer questions that do more than one thing wrong.  Consider it part of the puzzle, I guess.

Comment: thanks for your advice. i upvoted you, but chose davids' answer as it was closed to the solution. i must admit i initially had no sharing, as that made the most sense. i had been trying a few different combinations out, and had neglected to notice i had used the bitmask value GENERIC_WRITE in place of GENERIC_READ. the perils of cut and paste!

Comment: This is a common problem at SO, programmers tend to post their code after hacking it to pieces trying to solve the original problem.  Well, at least I explained why your original desire to flush the view isn't ever going to go anywhere.  Scratch that feature.

Comment: well actually, there are a few commercial products that use this approach rather sucessfully, but we can agree to disagree.